# How to fix Nuxt.js 3 installation problem with @nuxtjs/composition-api@0.33.1?

Tags: vue.js, frontend, nuxt.js, pinia

I am trying to run a Nuxt.js 3 template that I've bought from Envato market but when I run npm install the following error shows up.

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @nuxtjs/composition-api@0.33.1
npm ERR! Found: nuxt@3.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/nuxt
npm ERR!   dev nuxt@"3.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer nuxt@"^2.15" from @nuxtjs/composition-api@0.33.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@nuxtjs/composition-api
npm ERR!   @nuxtjs/composition-api@"^0.33.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: nuxt@2.17.1
npm ERR! node_modules/nuxt
npm ERR!   peer nuxt@"^2.15" from @nuxtjs/composition-api@0.33.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@nuxtjs/composition-api
npm ERR!     @nuxtjs/composition-api@"^0.33.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See C:\Users\20101\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\20101\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-09-20T19_07_39_414Z-debug-0.log
```

Has anybody faced a similar problem and if so how to fix it ?

Comment: Can you contact Evanto and/or the author?  I would expect reasonable support from the person or service I buy code from if it doesn't work.

Comment: Actually I did but I'm in a hurry and the procedure seems to take more time than I expected.

Answer (score 1):

The `@nuxtjs/composition-api` its a package to ensure **compatibility** with Vue 3 composition API and Nuxt 3 functions **while using Nuxt 2**. This allows to **easily migrate from Nuxt 2 to Nuxt 3**.

If you bought a ***"Nuxt 3"*** template this is **completely wrong** because an App using this package is a Nuxt 2 App, **NOT a Nuxt 3 App!!**

If your `package.json` has `"nuxt": "^3.0"` you can safely remove the `@nuxtjs/composition-api` dependency since **both can't work together**.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is a Nuxt 3 Template? Nuxt 3 doesn't support `@nuxtjs/composition-api` because its built on Vue 3 and it comes with the composition api.

Comment: That's the problem. The Envato team announced it as a Nuxt 3 one and package.json contains Nuxt 3 as dependency but I know that's not right. I've tried to remove it or downgrade Nuxt but that only makes it more complicated.